# Analytical solution, equation of 5 variables with quadratic components

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the function $f = x + y + z$ and conditions $g = 0 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 -1$ and $h =x-y-z-1=0$ one can find the max/min of the function $f$ with Lagrange's method, leading to the set of equations:

$1 = 2\lambda_1x + \lambda_2$

$1 = 2\lambda_1y - \lambda_2$

$1 = 2\lambda_1z - \lambda_2$

$0 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1$

$0 = x-y-z -1$

I can solve this numerically in matlab but how (if at all possible) would you solve this analytically? There is no way I know of to set this up as $Ax = b$, there is a quadratic equation in all 3 variables and $\lambda$ is coupled with $x,y,z$.

Edit: Ty for pointing out in comments the incorrect sign.

Comment: OK, now divide the first three equations by $\lambda_1$, and call $1\over\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2\over\lambda_1$ your new variables. You'll still have five equations, and all but one will be **linear**. Use the linear equations to exclude all but one variable, and solve the remaining quadratic equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the equations

$$1 = 2\lambda_1x + \lambda_2\tag{1}$$

$$1 = 2\lambda_1y - \lambda_2\tag{2}$$

$$1 = 2\lambda_1z - \lambda_2\tag{3}$$

$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2=1\tag{4}$$

$$x-y-z=1\tag{5}$$

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives

$$1=\lambda_1(x+y)\tag{6}$$

Adding $(1)$ and $(3)$ gives

$$1=\lambda_1(x+z)$$

From these two equations we get $x+y=x+z$ so that $y=z$.

Substituting into $(5)$ and rearranging gives

$$x=1+2y\tag{7}$$

Substituting this into $(4)$ gives

$$(1+2y)^2+y^2+y^2=1$$

which has solutions $y=0$ and $y=-2/3$.

- If $y=z=0$ then $(7)$ gives $x=1$. Equations $(6)$ and $(2)$ give $\lambda_1=1$, and $\lambda_2=-1$.
- If $y=z=-2/3$ then $(7)$ gives $x=-1/3$. Equations $(6)$ and $(2)$ give $\lambda_1=-1$ and $\lambda_2=1/3$.